# Concurrent writes to log file with pantheios from multiple processes

Tags: c++, logging, pantheios

Anyone knows if pantheios supports concurrent writing to log file from multiple processes . If I start two instances of my program, then nothing is written to the log file. Should I set some parameter in the library so this can work, or it is just not supported ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this is 3 months ago but still a relevant unanswered question. We had this problem and found that it's documented [here for Windows](http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html/group__group____backend____stock__backends____file____flags.html):

You need to set the PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_SHARE_ON_WINDOWS flag so that the share mode parameter passed to CreateFile() in the be_file_Context::Open() method (pantheios bec.file.cpp) includes FILE_SHARE_WRITE.

For example, your pantheios_be_file_setFilePath() call could be:

```
pantheios_be_file_setFilePath(your_path_name.c_str(),
  PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_SHARE_ON_WINDOWS,
  PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_SHARE_ON_WINDOWS,
  PANTHEIOS_BEID_ALL);
```